# Why won't Tortoise SVN update my ready to go green check folders? (for Garrys Mod)

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Whenever I try to update my Wire Mod folders by right clicking Tortoise SVN doesn't appear. There are no options regarding Tortoise SVN when I right click on the files at all. Im fairly angry now because I cant update it and I cant play Garrys Mod correctly without errors and pop ups telling me to update wiremod. I have (x86) as my program files on my "D" drive and I downloaded the 64-bit version of Tortoise too. It was working fine before but now it doesnt....please help me!?

Comment: You might check this old question on SO which seems to be talking about the shell extensions you seem to be missing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057734/tortoisesvn-icons-not-showing-up-under-windows-7 (I'm not sure about the discussion of 'icons' but I've never used Tortoise SVN - I'm guessing the shell extensions were headed by icons?)

Comment: This did explain the problem to me thank you, but I don't really know how to fix the problem know that I really know about it :C

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cleanup](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html) feature, there is an option which [refreshes the shell overlays](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html). This usually does the trick. Or you could delete the hidden .svn folder in the root of the directory and then checkout again. Sometimes they appear after a system restart. Recently I haven't noticed them to get stuck though, maybe it was happening more often before I switched to Windows 10 but that might be a fallacy.